# Launch Chrome.exe in minimized state? (Visual C++)

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, minimize

I'm trying to get Chrome to launch from a button click, but I want it to be in a minimized state so that it doesn't layer over the actual visual C++ form application.

I'm trying the below but not having any luck, any tips? This is my code;

> Process^ launchChrome = gcnew Process();
>
> launchChrome->StartInfo->UseShellExecute = false;
>
> launchChrome->StartInfo->FileName = "C:\Program FIles (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe";
>
> launchChrome->StartInfo->WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle::Minimized;
>
> launchChrome->Start();

Comment: AFAIK, Chrome doesn't take the [STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) value into account unfortunately (and the system doesn't require it to do so). Your best bet is trying to find if Chrome supports a command line switch that would allow you to launch it in a minimized state. Or worse, using some kind of `FindWindow` trick to minimize it manually.

Comment: ProcessWindowStyle::Minimized is just advisory, it is up to the program you start to pay attention to it.  And no, Chrome is not the kind of program that thinks that starting minimized is good for business.  Using "IExplore.exe" for the FileName is a workaround (delete the UseShellExeute assignment), it is humble.